# To find the best Projects depending on the Project Likes, Project Connected and Project Rating

Tags: c#, linq

I have this table:

PL_ProjectLikes
[image]

PC_ProjectConnect

[image]

PR_ProjectRating

[image]

P_Project

[image]

PL_PageLayout

[image]

This is my link query:

```
List<PProject> p = ctx.PProject.Where(x => x.PCountryCode == cC && x.PParentalGuidence == r).ToList();
List<PlPageLayout> pppp = ctx.PlPageLayout.Where(x => p.Select(n => n.PIdG).Contains(x.PlPId)).ToList();
```

Now PL_PageLayout has a field called PL_P_Id or PlPId, this is a guid.

What i want is to take theses tables figure out a rating or sum or count to pull the best projects to be filtered at the top of the list.

What i have done to extract each of these tables by grouping them with the PIdG which is a guid and is liked to each of the tables from the project and each project is a PL_PageLayout.

Extracted values from the tables:

PL_ProjectLIke:

```
var plike = ctx.PlProjectLike.Where(x => x.PlValue == "Like").Select(c => c).GroupBy(g => new { g.PlPIdG }, (key, group) => new { sumR = group.Count(), pidG = key.PlPIdG });
                List<string> p0p = plike.Select(t => t.pidG).ToList();
```

PR_ProjectRating:

```
var prating = ctx.PrProjectRating.Where(x => x.PrIsDeleted == false).Select(k => k).GroupBy(g => new { g.PrPIdG }, (key, group) => new { sumR = group.Sum(k => k.PrValue), pidG = key.PrPIdG });
                List<string> p0 = prating.Select(t => t.pidG).ToList();
```

PC_ProjectConnect:

```
var pconnect = ctx.PcProjectConnect.Where(x => x.PcStatus == "Connected").Select(c => c).GroupBy(g => new { g.PcPIdG }, (key, group) => new { sumR = group.Count(), pidG = key.PcPIdG });
                List<string> p0pp = pconnect.Select(t => t.pidG).ToList();
```

How do i combine these filters above to find the best projects or pagelayouts using linq?

I tried this:

```
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Which works and gets the best projects by the sum of the ratings for each project, but how do i combine the other two querys to find the best project?

Would this be the answer or would this just get the query of the last set:

```
                List<PlPageLayout> pppp = ctx.PlPageLayout.Where(x => p.Select(n => n.PIdG).Contains(x.PlPId)).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0p.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0p.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0pp.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0p.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Every time im liking a project as im testing its pushing the project down the list so that bit of code above is not working but making some progress

```
                List<PlPageLayout> pppp = ctx.PlPageLayout.Where(x => p.Select(n => n.PIdG).Contains(x.PlPId)).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0p.Contains(c.PlPId) ? p0p.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
                pppp = pppp.OrderBy(c => p0pp.Contains(c.PlPId) ? **p0pp**.IndexOf(c.PlPId) : int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help of this answer:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65014531/summing-a-value-inside-of-a-anonymous-type
```

I added the following code to get the best projects:

```
                  var ratings =
                from r1 in ctx.PrProjectRating
                where r1.PrIsDeleted == false
                group r1.PrValue by r1.PrPIdG into g
                select new
                {
                Id = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(),
                };
                var likes =
                    from l in ctx.PlProjectLike
                    where l.PlValue == "Like"
                    group 1 by l.PlPIdG into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count(),
                    };
                var connects =
                    from c1 in ctx.PcProjectConnect
                    where c1.PcStatus == "Connected"
                    group 1 by c1.PcPIdG into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count(),
                    };

                var ids = ratings.Select(r => r.Id)
                    .Union(likes.Select(l => l.Id))
                    .Union(connects.Select(c => c.Id))
                    .ToHashSet();
                var query =
                    from i in ids
                    join ra in ratings on i equals ra.Id into rs
                    from ra in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join l in likes on i equals l.Id into ls
                    from l in ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join co in connects on i equals co.Id into cs
                    from co in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Ratings = ra?.Sum ?? 0,
                        Likes = l?.Count ?? 0,
                        Connects = co?.Count ?? 0,
                    };
                List<PlPageLayout> pppp = ctx.PlPageLayout.Where(x => p.Select(n => n.PIdG).Contains(x.PlPId)).ToList();
                pppp = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Ratings + x.Likes + x.Connects).SelectMany(j => pppp.Where(s => s.PlPId == j.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have put some test code together at [RexTester](https://rextester.com/LESO14904) but I am not sure of your question.  I think you can just order the result lists as they are created, or am I just misunderstanding the question

```
public class PlProjectLike
{
    public int PlId { get; set; }
    public Guid PlPIdG { get; set; }
    public int PlUId { get; set; }
    public string PlValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlCreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class PcProjectConnect
{
    public int PcId { get; set; }
    public Guid PcPIdG { get; set; }
    public int PcUId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PcCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string PcStatus{ get; set; }
}

public class PrProjectRating
{
    public int PrId { get; set; }
    public int PrUId { get; set; }
    public string PrText { get; set; }
    public int PrValue { get; set; }
    public Guid PrPIdG { get; set; }
    public DateTime PrCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool PrIsDeleted{ get; set; }
}

public class PProject
{
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public Guid PIdG { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PDateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool PDeleted { get; set; }
    public int PUId { get; set; }
    public int PTtId { get; set; }
    public string PCountry { get; set; }
    public string PCountryCode { get; set; }
    public string PParentalGuidence { get; set; }
    public string PConnectionType { get; set; }
}

public class PlPageLayout
{
    public int PLId { get; set; }
    public Guid PlPId { get; set; }
    public string PLName { get; set; }
}

public class CTX
{
    public List<PProject> PProject { get; set; }
    public List<PlPageLayout> PlPageLayout { get; set; }
    public List<PlProjectLike> PlProjectLike { get; set; }
    public List<PrProjectRating> PrProjectRating { get; set; }
    public List<PcProjectConnect> PcProjectConnect { get; set; }

    public CTX()
    {
        PProject = new List<PProject>();
        PlPageLayout = new List<PlPageLayout>();
        PlProjectLike = new List<PlProjectLike>();
        PrProjectRating = new List<PrProjectRating>();
        PcProjectConnect = new List<PcProjectConnect>();
    }
}

public class LikeGroup
{
    public int sumR { get; set; }
    public Guid pidG { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CTX ctx = new CTX();
        String r = "R";
        string cC = "us";

        // Select project for country and rating
        List<PProject> p = ctx.PProject.Where(x => x.PCountryCode == cC && x.PParentalGuidence == r).ToList();
        // List of PlPageLayouts where the PlPId is in the selected PProject list
        List<PlPageLayout> pppp = ctx.PlPageLayout.Where(x => p.Select(n => n.PIdG).Contains(x.PlPId)).ToList();
        // List of Count/PlPIdG from PlProjectLike where the PlValue is 'Like' Ordered by the count descending
        List<LikeGroup> plike = ctx.PlProjectLike.Where(x => x.PlValue == "Like").Select(c => c).GroupBy(g => new { g.PlPIdG }, (key, group) => new LikeGroup() { sumR = group.Count(), pidG = key.PlPIdG }).OrderByDescending(dat => dat.sumR).ToList();
        // List of Sum(PrValue)/PlPIdG from PrProjectRating where PrIsDeleted is false Ordered by the Sum(PrValue) descending
        List<LikeGroup> prating = ctx.PrProjectRating.Where(x => x.PrIsDeleted == false).Select(k => k).GroupBy(g => new { g.PrPIdG }, (key, group) => new LikeGroup(){ sumR = group.Sum(k => k.PrValue), pidG = key.PrPIdG }).OrderByDescending(dat => dat.sumR).ToList();
        // List of Count/PlPIdG from PcProjectConnect where PcStatus is Connected Ordered by the count descending
        List<LikeGroup> pconnect = ctx.PcProjectConnect.Where(x => x.PcStatus == "Connected").Select(c => c).GroupBy(g => new { g.PcPIdG }, (key, group) => new LikeGroup() { sumR = group.Count(), pidG = key.PcPIdG }).OrderByDescending(dat => dat.sumR).ToList();

        List<PlProjectLike> OrderedProjectLikeList = 
            (from pl in ctx.PlProjectLike 
             join ord in plike on pl.PlPIdG equals ord.pidG 
             orderby ord.sumR descending 
             select pl).ToList();

        List<PrProjectRating> OrderedPrProjectRatingList = 
            (from pr in ctx.PrProjectRating
             join ord in prating on pr.PrPIdG equals ord.pidG
             orderby ord.sumR descending
             select pr).ToList();

        List<PcProjectConnect> OrderedPcProjectConnectList =
            (from pc in ctx.PcProjectConnect
             join ord in prating on pc.PcPIdG equals ord.pidG
             orderby ord.sumR descending
             select pc).ToList();

    }
}
```