# Summing a value inside of a Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, linq

I have this in my code:

```
var pRating = ctx.PrProjectRating
   .Where(x => x.PrIsDeleted == false)
   .Select(k => k)
   .GroupBy(g =>
      new {g.PrPIdG},
      (key, group) => new
         {
            sumR = group.Sum(k => k.PrValue),
            pidG = key.PrPIdG
         });

var pLike = ctx.PlProjectLike
   .Where(x => x.PlValue == "Like")
   .Select(c => c)
   .GroupBy(g =>
      new {g.PlPIdG},
      (key, group) => new
         {
            sumR = group.Count(),
            pidG = key.PlPIdG
         })
   .OrderByDescending(g => g.sumR);

var pConnect = ctx.PcProjectConnect
   .Where(x => x.PcStatus == "Connected")
   .Select(c => c)
   .GroupBy(g =>
      new {g.PcPIdG},
      (key, group) => new
         {
            sumR = group.Count(),
            pidG = key.PcPIdG
         })
   .OrderByDescending(g => g.sumR);
```

How do i combine these collections and sum the sumR value together?

### EDIT

```
pRating =
pidG          sumR
123           11
124           7
125           5

pLike =
pidG          sumR
123           3
125           2

pConnect =
pidG          sumR
125           5
```

Result should be:

```
pResult =
pidG          sumR
123           15
125           12
124           7
```

i need to group the pidG together and sum them up using sumR

I wanted to get the list of pidG values group them and find the count or sum and order them by the highest sum value and thats what you see in the collections above and in the table diagram.

Then i need to grab the sum and group the collections to find that its ordered by the highest value of sumR

### EDIT

im trying to do this:

```
var query =
                    from i in ids
                    join ra in ratings on i equals ra.Id into rs
                    from ra in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join l in likes on i equals l.Id into ls
                    from l in ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join co in connects on i equals co.Id into cs
                    from co in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Total = ra?.Sum ?? 0 + l?.Count ?? 0 + co?.Count ?? 0,
                        Ratings = ra?.Sum ?? 0,
                        Likes = l?.Count ?? 0,
                        Connects = co?.Count ?? 0,
                    };
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total);
```

But does not sum the total which i need.

Comment: Define "combine" here. They seem to be three completely independent tables as far as we know. How are they related? What would your result look like?

Comment: The results from each collection comes back as <int, string> or <sumR, pidG> so there is a relation but its an anonymous type

Comment: So you're saying the `PrPIdG`, `PlPIdG` and `PcPIdG` are the keys for each?

Comment: Each collection has duplicate pidG values so i need to group each collection by pidG and sum up the results using sumR

Comment: yes the extention pidG is the unique field in each collection and is contained in each collection

Comment: im just trying to get the sum of each collection that corresponds to the pidG value in each collection

Comment: If you have multiple expressions creating anonymously-typed objects, and the objects have the same property names, types and order, then they are all the same type. If you have multiple IEnumerables representing collections of these things, call `ToList` on one of them and then `AddRange` to coalesce everything into a single collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do all the queries separately as subqueries, then do a full join to combine the results on the client.

```
var ratings =
    from r in ctx.PrProjectRating
    where !r.PrIsDeleted
    group r.PrValue by r.PrPIdG into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Sum = g.Sum(),
    };
var likes =
    from l in ctx.PlProjectLike
    where l.PlValue == "Like"
    group 1 by l.PlPIdG into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
var connects =
    from c in ctx.PcProjectConnect
    where c.PcStatus == "Connected"
    group 1 by c.PcPIdG into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
```

```
var ids = ratings.Select(r => r.Id)
    .Union(likes.Select(l => l.Id))
    .Union(connects.Select(c => c.Id))
    .ToHashSet();
var query =
    from i in ids
    join r in ratings on i equals r.Id into rs
    from r in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join l in likes on i equals l.Id into ls
    from l in ls.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join c in connects on i equals c.Id into cs
    from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Id = i,
        Ratings = r?.Sum ?? 0,
        Likes = l?.Count ?? 0,
        Connects = c?.Count ?? 0,
    };
```

Comment: You may need to add `AsEnumerable()` calls to each of the subqueries.